# Nginx wordpress proxy pass

Tags: nginx, wordpress, nginx-reverse-proxy

after hours of trying and google i thought my last chance to get it solved is here.

i have the following problem:

- A Wordpress page is running under myperfectshop.com
- The shop just have one product at the moment, which is located under myperfectshop.com/product/first
- Till there are further products i want that everyone will get redirected from the URL "/" to "/product/first"
- This should happen with a proxy pass, so that the URL will remain "/"

i have tried the following code:

```
...
        location = / {
                proxy_pass https://myperfectshop.com/product/first
        }
        
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        }

...
```

But this example will end up in an infinity loop for the root path. all other paths are working fine.

Can somebody please explaine me what i am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.